# PHP: Trouble accessing JSON object/array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, stdclass

I was wondering if I could please get some help with the following mistake that I am making...

I am trying to access data in a weather api and I can't seem to echo out the information that I need.

```
<?php
// fetch Aeris API output as a string and decode into an object
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.aerisapi.com/observations/closest?p=:auto&format=json&radius=50mi&filter=allstations&limit=5&fields=id,ob.tempF,ob.dewpointF,ob.humidity,ob.windSpeedMPH,ob.windDir,ob.weather,ob.heatindexF,ob.feelslikeF&client_id=fRqZ7kEn97lvuYQlIFZ8y&client_secret=GKl5UydVJoSP7UDxmXWx5J8pegsFybclACCyVksr");
$json = json_decode($response);

foreach ($json->response as $weather);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($weather);
echo 'weather'->[ob];
```

?>

I get the following error:

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\wamp64\www\aeris\aerisobs.php on line 10

I'm not sure what the error is?

If we just look at what $weather prints out as, it's the following:

```
C:\wamp64\www\aeris\aerisobs.php:9:
object(stdClass)[10]
public 'id' => string 'MID_F5795' (length=9)
public 'ob' => 
object(stdClass)[11]
  public 'tempF' => int 68
  public 'dewpointF' => int 64
  public 'humidity' => int 88
  public 'windSpeedMPH' => int 1
  public 'windDir' => string 'NE' (length=2)
  public 'weather' => string 'Cloudy with Mist and Fog' (length=24)
  public 'heatindexF' => int 68
  public 'feelslikeF' => int 68
```

If anyone would be so kind as to educate me on my error and how to access ob and then, for example, tempF and print out 68 so that I can get that to appear on a web page?

Thank you for any assistance that you may offer!

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but this should work for you to get inner values of `ob` using another `foreach()`, also your first `foreach()` **had some syntax error**, have a look on my below answer. This should work for sure to get the values inside `$weather->ob`

```
<?php
// fetch Aeris API output as a string and decode into an object
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.aerisapi.com/observations/closest?p=:auto&format=json&radius=50mi&filter=allstations&limit=5&fields=id,ob.tempF,ob.dewpointF,ob.humidity,ob.windSpeedMPH,ob.windDir,ob.weather,ob.heatindexF,ob.feelslikeF&client_id=fRqZ7kEn97lvuYQlIFZ8y&client_secret=GKl5UydVJoSP7UDxmXWx5J8pegsFybclACCyVksr");
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->response as $weather)
{
    echo '<pre>'; 
    #var_dump($weather);
    #print_r($weather->ob);
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach($weather->ob as $key=>$value){
        if($key =='tempF'){
          echo "$key = $value";
          echo "<br/>";
        }
       
    }
}
?>
```

Basically you need to iterate on your $weather->ob to get the inner values. Let's say you need only the **tempF** value from the inner object then you can put an if a condition like above to print that only if you need all values inside the $weather->ob then just remove the condition

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": "MID_C3868",
            "ob": {
                "tempF": 68,
                "dewpointF": 66,
                "humidity": 94,
                "windSpeedMPH": 1,
                "windDir": "NNE",
                "weather": "Cloudy with Mist and Fog",
                "heatindexF": 68,
                "feelslikeF": 68
            }
        },
        {

Comment: @JustinPerry just copy my code block, paste here http://phpfiddle.org/ and run it is working I've checked it now

Comment: @JustinPerry if that works, tick on the green tick to mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Would it be possible to show how to access individual elements inside of each ob?  For eaxmple, show only 'tempF' from an ob?

Comment: AND, if I can be completely needy, is there any chance of a small explanation as to why/how this code works?